# Backbone Error: Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'on'

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Any ideas why am I getting this error when I invoke `collection.fetch`?

It's thrown in this section of the code:

[image: Backbone Error]

This is the code that triggers the error:

```
$(document).ready ->
  SearchResult = Backbone.Model.extend

  SearchResults = Backbone.Collection.extend
    url: "/backbone/search"
    model: SearchResult
    parse: (response)->
      console.log response
      new SearchResult
        id: response.id
        title: response.title


  searchResults = new SearchResults()

  searchResults.fetch()
```

Comment: you need to return an object which can be passed into `new SearchResult` to obtain a search result.  If you look at the Collections.Fetch code, it uses the results of parse to pass to add (which determines if it's an array or a single object; for the array it'll loop through them, for the single object it'll just pass that directly to _add)

Answer (score 8):

The problem was with this line of code:

```
SearchResult = Backbone.Model.extend
```

It should have been like this:

```
SearchResult = Backbone.Model.extend()
```

Otherwise CoffeeScript was assigning the `extend` function to SearchResult

Comment: I just ran into the same error message, and this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually attaching the models to the collection...

from the docs, parse should

> return the array of model attributes to be added to the collection.

```
$(document).ready ->
  SearchResult = Backbone.Model.extend

  SearchResults = Backbone.Collection.extend
    url: "/backbone/search"
    model: SearchResult
    parse: (response) ->
      _.map response, (item) ->
          id: item.id
          title: item.title

  searchResults = new SearchResults()    
  searchResults.fetch()
```

I haven't tested it, but i believe that will work